# How to take a special part from every list elements with different length

Tags: r, list

The data format looks like:
"Gender-Bornyear-name-country"
so, data listed as:

```
[[1]] M-1900-Chambers-us
[[2]] F-1900-Calin-Sanchez-es
[[3]] M-1900-Aboul-Enein-us
...
...
```

I try to use

```
strsplit(as.charactoe(data), "\\-")
```

but some of the name just split to one part, some split to two or three. 
If I just want to withdarw the country

```
split_data <- strsplit(as.charactoe(data), "\\-")
lapply(split_data, function(x)x[length(x)])
```

Is this the best way?
How about if I want to take the name out?

Comment: It's certainly not a 'bad' way - it's pretty much how i'd do it, with the exception of the typo `charactoe` and using `tail, 1` instead of the `x[length(x)]` function. If you have some rules about which parts correspond to what fields, you should be able to adapt your code to take the first 1 or 2 splits, the middle set of splits, or the last split as you already have figured out.

Comment: If it's always a two-character code you could use `substr` with `nchar`, but it's about the same complexity.

Comment: you can also use regex: `sub('.*?-([^-]+$)', '\\1', 'M-1900-Aboul-Enein-us')` gives `us`.

Comment: @mt1022 even `gsub("([[:alnum:]].*-){1}", "", x)` this worked to get the country. However I wanted to know how to extract the `name`. i.e. c("Chambers", "Calin-Sanchez", "Aboul-Enein"). Could you help me out?

Comment: @joel.wilson, you could try `gsub('.*?\\d+-(.*?)-[^-]+$', '\\1', x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmark test results (all the three options extract the country names with the sample data provided), gsub is the fastest:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(data), "\\-"), function(x)x[length(x)]))
#[1] "us" "es" "us"
gsub('.*-([^-]+)$', '\\1', data)
#[1] "us" "es" "us"
do.call(rbind, str_match_all(data, '.*-([^-]+)$'))[,2]
#[1] "us" "es" "us"

library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)
check.identical <- function(values) {
   all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(values[[1]], x)))
}
microbenchmark(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(data), "\\-"), function(x)x[length(x)])), 
                   gsub('.*-([^-]+)$', '\\1', data), 
                   do.call(rbind, str_match_all(data, '.*-([^-]+)$'))[,2], 
                   check=check.identical)

Unit: microseconds
                                                                          expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(data), "\\\\-"), function(x) x[length(x)])) 15.396 16.4655 20.09603 18.3895 20.3145  87.670   100  b 
                                             gsub(".*-([^-]+)$", "\\\\1", data) 11.975 13.6850 15.31916 15.3960 16.6790  27.799   100 a  
                        do.call(rbind, str_match_all(data, ".*-([^-]+)$"))[, 2] 35.923 37.6340 43.93346 39.7720 41.4830 149.679   100   c
```